# genoPlotR problem with plot_gene_map command

Tags: r

`plot_gene_map` command gave me the following  error:

> Error in plot_gene_map(dna_segs = data, comparisons = data_blast,
> seg_plot_height = 10,  :    Argument dna_segs must be a list of
> dna_seg objects

However I did use the same files previously without any problems.
Do you have some advices?

```
plot_gene_map(dna_segs=data, comparisons=data_blast, seg_plot_height=10, main="test1")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you please edit your post to include your data.  The following code will generate a code snippet with 10 random records that you can paste into your original post: dput(dplyr::sample_n(YourDatasetsNameGoesHere, 10)). To use my code, you may need to install dplyr with: install.packages("dplyr")

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
It was a problem of the R version. The packages I used required the last version.